# Como faço para calcular o média de tempo de execução de uma função?

Tags: python

Para calcular o tempo de execução de uma função estou utilizando

```
inicio=time.time()
# código 
fim=time.time()
```

Como faço para calcular o tempo repetidas vezes e depois calcular a média desse tempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar o trecho de código que você está medindo a execução dentro de um laço:

```
import time

REPETICOES = 10
tempos = []
for vezes in range(0, REPETICOES):
    inicio = time.time()
    # ... o código a medir entra aqui ... #
    fim = time.time()
    tempos.append(fim - inicio)

media = sum(tempos) / REPETICOES
```

Ou então usar o módulo `timeit`:

```
import timeit

REPETICOES = 10

# o seu código fica dentro de uma string mesmo
meu_codigo = """
j = 0
for i in range(0,999):
    j += i * j
"""

tempo = timeit.timeit(stmt=meu_codigo, number=REPETICOES)
print(tempo / REPETICOES)
```

Mas você pode perceber que em ambos, seja "manualmente" ou através da biblioteca, as implementações são bastante parecidas.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma interessante que o Python te permite fazer é criar um decorador que gerencie isso para você:

```
def time_statistics(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()

        if not hasattr(wrapper, 'times'):
            wrapper.times = []

        wrapper.times.append(end - start)
        return result

    return wrapper
```

Assim, na função que você quer analisar, basta fazer:

```
@time_statistics
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Efetuar as chamadas para testar o tempo:

```
for _ in range(100):
    foo(1, 2)
```

Depois analisar os resultados:

```
print('Tempo mínimo [s]: ', min(foo.times))
print('Tempo máximo [s]: ', max(foo.times))
print('Média de tempo [s]: ', sum(foo.times) / len(foo.times))
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SimplisticTomatoOutliers).

**Dica:** eu utilizei uma lista simples para gerenciar os tempos, mas você pode facilmente abstrair isso numa estrutura mais complexa que já gerencie toda a lógica que necessita, seja calculando mínimos e máximo, calculando a média, desvio padrão, variância, seja gerando o gráfico.